# Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT

Tags: sql-server, transactions, entity-framework-6

When any error occur in the following proc then error message is "Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous `count = 1, current count = 0`. Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous `count = 1, current count = 0`"

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_PurchaseOrder_Create](@CustomerID INT, @CustomerOrderID INT OUTPUT)          
AS          
SET NOCOUNT ON;          
--------------------------------          
DECLARE @Return_Message VARCHAR(1024)          
DECLARE @ErrorCode  INT            
DECLARE @ErrorStep  VARCHAR(200)          
DECLARE @UserID INT  
--------------------------------          
DECLARE @CustomerCartID INT,@PONumber VARCHAR(255), @CartTotalAmount NUMERIC          

BEGIN TRY          

    BEGIN TRAN                  
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------             
  SELECT @ErrorCode = @@ERROR          
      SET NOCOUNT ON;      
  IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT CustomerCartID FROM TxnCustomerCart WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID)           
     BEGIN          
        SET @Return_Message= 'No Cart item is available'          
           SET @ErrorCode = 1          
        END                  
        ELSE          
        BEGIN          
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------          
    SELECT @UserID = ISNULL(UserID,0) FROM TxnCustomers WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID      
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------          
    SELECT @CartTotalAmount = CartTotalAmount, @CustomerCartID = CustomerCartID FROM TxnCustomerCart WHERE @CustomerID = CustomerID            
    SELECT @ErrorStep = 'Error on inserting data into TxnCustomerOrders';            
    INSERT INTO TxnCustomerOrders(CustomerID,OrderDate,OrderStatus,Ramarks,PaymentCategoryCode,CreatedBy,CreatedDatetime)          
    VALUES(@CustomerID,GETDATE(),'PRTRCVD','','Wallet',@UserID,GETDATE())            
    SET @CustomerOrderID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();          

    SELECT @ErrorStep = 'Error on generating PONumber';            
    SET @PONumber =dbo.fun_getPONumber(@CustomerID, @CustomerOrderID)          

    SELECT @ErrorStep = 'Error on inserting data into TxnPurchaseOrder';          

    INSERT INTO TxnPurchaseOrder (CustomerOrderID, PONumber, PODate, POAmount, PODocID, PODocPath, CreatedBy, CreatedDate)          
     VALUES (@CustomerOrderID, @PONumber, GETDATE(), @CartTotalAmount, REPLACE(@PONumber, '/' , '-'), REPLACE(@PONumber, '/' , '-') + '.pdf', @UserID, GETDATE())              

    SELECT  @ErrorCode  = 0, @Return_Message = 'Purchase order successfully created'          
  END       

  SET NOCOUNT OFF;         
    COMMIT TRAN               
    RETURN @ErrorCode -- =0 if success,  <>0 if failure          
END TRY           
BEGIN CATCH          
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK          

    SELECT @ErrorCode = ERROR_NUMBER()          
        , @Return_Message = @ErrorStep + ' '          
        + cast(ERROR_NUMBER() as varchar(20)) + ' line: '          
     + cast(ERROR_LINE() as varchar(20)) + ' '           
        + ERROR_MESSAGE() + ' > '           
        + ERROR_PROCEDURE()          

    RETURN @ErrorCode -- =0 if success,  <>0 if failure          

END CATCH
```

Comment: your sp is surrounded with another transaction

Answer (score 3):

You need also to consider results of XACT_STATE() function. Check the block **Uncommittable Transactions and XACT_STATE** on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx)

---

**LATER EDIT**

---

I changed my mind about a possible solution :)
Finally I got your situation reproduced. Look.
I took your procedure, removed all code except the code related to exception handling and `try\catch` logic and added expression which will cause object name resolution error (fatal error). Here's what I got

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_PurchaseOrder_Create]         
AS          
SET NOCOUNT ON;          
BEGIN TRY          

    BEGIN TRAN   

    print 'before'
    select * from ##global_tmp_table; --> fatal error here
    print 'after'

    COMMIT TRAN         
END TRY           
BEGIN CATCH
    print 'catch'
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK          
END CATCH
```

Ok, now if I try to execute this procedure I got the following output

*before
Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Procedure proc_PurchaseOrder_Create, Line 29
Invalid object name '##global_tmp_table'.
Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure proc_PurchaseOrder_Create, Line 29
Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1.*

So, what happened? - **Our transaction remains open** - you can check this by executing `print @@TRANCOUNT` in the same window

why this happened? - **because the catch block can't catch fatal errors** - from the same MSDN [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) I mentioned earlier

*The following types of errors are not handled by a CATCH block when they occur at the same level of execution as the TRY…CATCH construct:
Compile errors, such as syntax errors, that prevent a batch from running.
Errors that occur during statement-level recompilation, such as object name resolution errors that occur after compilation because of deferred name resolution.*

Before we will fix this situation you need to call `ROLLBACK` in the window where you tried to execute stored procedure in order to finally close our transaction.

And how we can fix that? - we just need to `set XACT_ABORT ON` - you can find an example in all the same article in the **Using TRY…CATCH with XACT_STATE** block

So, finally, our test procedure should look like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_PurchaseOrder_Create]         
AS          
SET NOCOUNT ON;  
SET XACT_ABORT ON; --> the only change
BEGIN TRY          

    BEGIN TRAN   

    print 'before'
    select * from ##global_tmp_table;
    print 'after'

    COMMIT TRAN         
END TRY           
BEGIN CATCH
    print 'catch'
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK          
END CATCH
```

And now, in a case of fatal error database engine will automatically roll back the transaction and you will get only the expected error message

*before
Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Procedure proc_PurchaseOrder_Create, Line 31
Invalid object name '##global_tmp_table'.*

Comment: couple of things here, first one is do i need to keep "IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK" as is it and second one is why/when this issue occures.

Comment: Hi, @andrey  i got your solution and it is working exactly you have explained in sql server. But the problem is that when i calling this procedure from my C#.net using entity framework 6 code and logging error on to the file following error log

Comment: ERROR [09 Mar 11:04:24][OLMPServices.Controllers.OrderManagementController.OrderPlacement(D:\VSS\Order Lifecycle Management Portal\400_S6_ImplementationAndUnitaryTest_Phase\Source Code\OLMP\Working\OLMP.root\OLMP\OLMPServices\Controllers\OrderManagementController.cs:242)]- System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.
Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.

Comment: Error on inserting data into TxnOrderAddressDetails 8152 line: 49 String or binary data would be truncated. > proc_PurchaseOrder_Create
   at OLMPBusiness.OrderManagementBusinessComponent.CreatePurchaseOrder(String authToken) in D:\VSS\Order Lifecycle Management Portal\400_S6_ImplementationAndUnitaryTest_Phase\Source Code\OLMP\Working\OLMP.root\OLMP\OLMPBusiness\OrderManagementBusinessComponent.cs:line 198
   at

Comment: OLMPServices.Controllers.OrderManagementController.OrderPlacement() in D:\VSS\Order Lifecycle Management Portal\400_S6_ImplementationAndUnitaryTest_Phase\Source Code\OLMP\Working\OLMP.root\OLMP\OLMPServices\Controllers\OrderManagementController.cs:line 232
ClientConnectionId:9bf7d1ec-ea49-49b6-a8e0-bc53d486d99d
Error Number:266,State:2,Class:16

Comment: Ok, now we finally got the reason why exception happens - you have truncation problems while inserting data into the TxnOrderAddressDetails table. In order to fix this you should check fields length in this table and probably increase length for some varchar/nvarchar field

Comment: No, i have given extra size value manually because in want to generate an error to see the out put of the procedure. Means when this kind of error will occur then how to handle using transaction and try catch.